# How to get the count of policies for rejection codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where i need to map the rejection codes and give the count of the Policies of Each type for Each rejection codes. Example mentioned as below.

Policy Table:

```
PolicyNo  | PolType |MyRejectionCode
----------|---------|--------------
Pol1      |   S     |   M101
----------|---------|--------------
Pol2      |   S     |   M101, M102
----------|---------|--------------
Pol3      |   S     |   M104
----------|---------|--------------
Pol4      |   F     |   M105, M107, M108
----------|---------|--------------
Pol5      |   F     |   M106
----------|---------|--------------
Pol6      |   F     |   M107
```

RejectionMapping Table:

```
    MyRejCode    | StandardRejCode      
-----------------|----------------
M101             |   S101
-----------------|----------------
M102             |   S102
-----------------|----------------
M103             |   S103
-----------------|----------------
M104             |   S104
-----------------|----------------
M105             |   S101
-----------------|----------------
M106             |   S102
-----------------|----------------
M107             |   S103
-----------------|----------------
M108             |   S104
```

Now i want to create a select query to give the  result in below format.

```
StandartRejCode  |  S_Pol_Type_Count  |     F_Pol_Type_Count
-----------------|--------------------|----------------------
    S101         |      2             |           1
-----------------|--------------------|----------------------
    S102         |      1             |           1  
-----------------|--------------------|----------------------
    S103         |      0             |           2     
-----------------|--------------------|----------------------
    S104         |      1             |           1
```

How can I create a query for mentioned output?

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: What he said, comma seperated values suck. But I guess you could check if the M10x policy is in the value by doing IS IN MyRejectionCode

Comment: Hi jarlh, unfortunately its the existing implementation so i cant change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @Policy AS TABLE (PolicyNo VARCHAR(100)  , PolType VARCHAR(100) ,MyRejectionCode VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Policy
SELECT 'Pol1','S','M101'            UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pol2','S','M101,M102'       UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pol3','S','M104'            UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pol4','F','M105,M107,M108'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pol5','F','M106'            UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pol6','F','M107'            

DECLARE @RejectionMapping AS  Table ( MyRejCode VARCHAR(100), StandardRejCode VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @RejectionMapping
SELECT 'M101','S101' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M102','S102' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M103','S103' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M104','S104' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M105','S101' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M106','S102' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M107','S103' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M108','S104'
```

Now We need to split the comma separated data into single row using xml format.
Then need to join both the tables using inner join and finally find the count of occurrences of "PolType"

```
;WITH Cte
AS
(
SELECT PolicyNo,PolType,Split.a.value ('.','nvarchar(max)') AS MyRejectionCode
FROM
(
SELECT PolicyNo,    PolType,
CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(MyRejectionCode,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) AS MyRejectionCode
FROM @Policy
)AS A
CROSS APPLY MyRejectionCode.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT R.StandardRejCode,      
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PolType = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS S_Pol_Type_Count,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PolType = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS F_Pol_Type_Count
FROM Cte c
INNER JOIN  @RejectionMapping R
    ON R.MyRejCode = c.MyRejectionCode
GROUP BY R.StandardRejCode
```

Result

```
StandardRejCode S_Pol_Type_Count    F_Pol_Type_Count
------------------------------------------------------
S101                    2                   1
S102                    1                   1
S103                    0                   2
S104                    1                   1
```

Comment: Very organized answer. I had a shorter one prepared using `like` on the join condition, but I'd rather the OP use the correct way rather than the eye-pleasing shorter one. Kudos.

Comment: Hi @Sreenu131 thanks for the answer. Works perfect. Just one thing, if i have duplicate Rejection Code for a policy, like below, then how can i just find the distinct count for that rejection code. In below case, M102 should be counted just once. 'Pol2','S','M101,M102,M102,M104'